# Connecting Native ios app to Salesforce1?

Tags: salesforce1-app, ios

I would like to connect my native ios app (objective C/ Bluetooth Low Energy)  in Salesforce1 platform (not as custom app). How do I do that ( publisher action or global actions or canvas apps) ?. Can you provide me pointers to documentation/ examples.

Thanks,
Vasu

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is currently NOT possible in Salesforce1. This is because

A) Canvas is for integrating external web applications and mobile-web based apps (both of which have a public URL) NOT native mobile applications which are installed and run on a user's device
B) Both custom Chatter publisher actions and global actions work with VF pages and Canvas apps NOT with native mobile apps

Read more [here](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=actions_overview.htm)

On the other hand, if you have a hybrid app which in turn invokes VF pages, you can still expose those via Salesforce1. However, it is NOT possible for 3rd party native apps. In fact, Salesforce has published [guidelines](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.186.0.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/dev_S1_vs_custom_apps.htm) on when you should opt for building native apps vs. using the Salesforce1 app.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav for taking time to answer my question. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry !! forgot to mention that the explanation was clear and concise. Thanks again !!!.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a one way to launch native app's on Salesforce1
http://www.meetingassistantapp.com/how-to-launch-native-apps-on-salesforce1/

Please let me know if it helps!

Comment: This looks great. I'm curious to hear that this worked or not.

Comment: Wow. This is great . I will check it out and let you know. Thanks for this.

Comment: Anything similar can we do to launch a native android app?

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across this post and thought will give you the latest response on launching native apps from Salesforce1

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/isv/2015/01/empower-salesforce1-solution-deep-link.html