# Opening iOS app from Salesforce1 App (v7.3.1)

Tags: javascript, ios, url, hybrid, mobile-url-scheme

I'm trying to open custom url scheme iOS app from Salesforce1 app.
Previously it was opening fine but since v7.3.1 release i cannot open external app anymore.

Instead of opening app it opens Salesforce1 page with error text:

> you can't view this page, either because you don't have permission or because the page isn't supported on mobile devices.

Tried this solution:
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/30368/24640

Prevous version of salesforce was working fine when using:

> window.top.location = 'myapp://'

and

> iframe.src = 'myapp://'

At the moment I'm not sure than if this is bug or salesforce changed something.

Comment: tried also use not recommended 
`sforce.one.navigateToURL` but no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to run app using a bit different link:

> window.top.location = 'myapp://home';

It need to be something after schema and before query string like in my example.

I think salesforce1 is validating a link and if it's empty after schema it throws an error.

Answer (score -1):

Just added  target="_blank" to my URL and the app pulls up again.